# Max SubArray Determination in Python

Tags: python

```
class index(object):

    def __init__(self,low,high,total):
        self.low = low
        self.high = high
        self.total = total
    def printing(self):
        print "Low:",self.low
        print "High:",self.high
        print "Total:",self.total

def max_crossing_subarray(A,low,mid,high):
    sum, left_sum = 0, -10000000       # Better limit for left_sum
    left_max = mid
    for i in xrange(mid-1,low-1,-1):
        sum += A[i]
        if sum > left_sum :
            left_sum = sum
            left_max = i

    sum, right_sum = 0, -10000000      # Better limit for right_sum
    right_max = mid
    for i in xrange(mid,high):
        sum += A[i]
        if sum > right_sum:
            right_sum = sum
            right_max = i

    total = left_sum + right_sum
    cross_sub = index(left_max,right_max,total)
    return cross_sub

def max_subarray(A,low,high):

    if low >= 0 and high < len(A):
        base = index(low,high,A[low])
        if high == low :
            return base
        else:
            mid = ( high + low )/2
            left = max_subarray(A,low,mid)
            right = max_subarray(A,mid+1,high)
            cross = max_crossing_subarray(A,low,mid,high)

        if left.total >= right.total and left.total >= cross.total:
            return left
        elif right.total >= left.total and right.total >= cross.total:
            return right
        else:
            return cross

def main():

    print "Enter a sequence:"
    A = map(int , raw_input().split())
    result = max_subarray(A,0,len(A))
    result.printing()
```

In order to determine the max subarray, I wrote the above code.
The problem I am getting is that, on compilation it shows:

I am a beginner in Python and would really like some guidance here.

Thank you.

EDIT:

Full backtrace log of exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main2.py", line 59, in <module>
    main()
  File "main2.py", line 57, in main
    result.printing()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'printing'
```

Comment: Can you post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Also check http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: In the main part you are giving the `max_subarray` function `len(A)` function which states how many elements does the `A` list have. Instead you should subtract one from it, because the intention (I think) was to give the span of looking for the subarray, hence `A[len(A)]`, wouldn't be correct.

`result = max_subarray(A, 0, len(A) - 1)`

Also I'm not sure whether your algorithm is correct, check what would happen if you were to give it an increasing sequence.

Comment: thank you. I got the mistake as you pointed out but now its down to my wrong algorithm and logic.
Any suggestions ? I dont want the solution

Comment: Whenever I would need to find a maximum subarray, I would try to solve it with dynamic programming, as in setting current and best solutions at start to 0, then going through each element of the list and assing those current and best solutions accordingly in loop. Some sort of current = max(next + current, 0) and best = max(current, best). But you would need to also remember the start and end indexes in some sort of way. This should give you o(1) space, but o(n) time, which should be still quite good for a max subarray finding algorithm.